# Getting Error "Exception while calling encodeEnd on component" in jboss 6.1.1 but running well in jboss 4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jboss, jsf-1.2

My project (jsf1.2 with Richfaces 3.3.4) is running well in JBoss 4.2 with the below jar files ..

```
acegi-security-1.0.6.jar        
activation.jar      
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar       
BPMTest.jar     
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar     
commons-codec-1.3.jar       
commons-collections-3.2.jar     
commons-dbcp.jar        
commons-digester-1.8.jar        
commons-discovery-0.4.jar       
commons-el.jar      
commons-fileupload-1.0.jar      
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar      
commons-io-1.0.jar      
commons-io-1.4.jar      
commons-lang-2.4.jar        
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar       
commons-pool-1.2.jar        
iText-2.1.3.jar     
javax.xml.stream-1.0.1.jar      
jaxb-xjc.jar        
jaxrs-api-1.1-RC2.jar       
jaxrs-api-1.1.GA.jar        
jsfExt.jar      
jsp-api.jar     
jsr173_1.0_api.jar      
jsr181-api.jar      
jxl.jar     
mail.jar        
myfaces-api-1.2.12.jar      
myfaces-impl-1.2.12.jar     
oscache-2.3.2.jar       
resolver.jar        
resteasy-jaxb-provider-1.1-RC2.jar      
resteasy-jaxb-provider-1.1.GA.jar       
resteasy-jaxrs-1.1-RC2.jar      
resteasy-jaxrs-1.1.GA.jar       
resteasy-spring-1.1-RC2.jar     
resteasy-spring-1.1.GA.jar      
richfaces-api-3.3.4.Final.jar       
richfaces-impl-3.3.4.Final.jar      
richfaces-ui-3.3.4.Final.jar        
saaj-api.jar        
saaj-impl.jar       
servlet-api-2.5.jar     
sjsxp.jar       
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar     
slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar      
spring.jar      
tomahawk.jar        
trinidad-api-1.0.12.jar     
trinidad-impl-1.0.12.jar        
xercesImpl.jar
```

But when I am trying to run it in Jboss 6.1.1 it is throwing the below error:

> Exception while calling encodeEnd on component : {Component-Path :
>   [Class: org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot,ViewId:
>   /pages/testLogin.jsp][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id:
>   frmTestLogin][Class:
>   javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectManyListbox,Id: userRegions]}
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException - Value of UISelectMany
>   component with path : {Component-Path : [Class:
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot,ViewId:
>   /pages/testLogin.jsp][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id:
>   frmTestLogin][Class:
>   javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectManyListbox,Id: userRegions]} is
>   not of type Array or List.

Please help me to figure out the problem. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case, there was a method that represented the same property as the list used in SelectManyCheckbox.

I changed the property from the list and it worked.